# Apigee127 : Usergrid download failure preventing Mocks from being tested

Tags: apigee, usergrid, apigee127

Thanks for the tip Scott, I did download it a second time & ensured the size is as you mentioned it needs to be:

```
C:\Users>a127 usergrid download
Downloading Usergrid and Portal as needed...
..............................................................................do
wnloaded
- 'C:\Users\sgs\.a127\usergrid\usergrid-launcher-0.0.29.jar'
- 'C:\Users\sgs\.a127\usergrid\usergrid-portal-2.0.16\usergrid-port
al\index.html'


C:\Users>cd sgs\.a127\usergrid

C:\Users\sgs\.a127\usergrid>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 1864-0DEB

 Directory of C:\Users\sgs\.a127\usergrid

11/30/2014  11:34 AM    <DIR>          .
11/30/2014  11:34 AM    <DIR>          ..
**11/30/2014  11:34 AM        48,581,037 usergrid-launcher-0.0.29.jar**
11/30/2014  11:33 AM    <DIR>          usergrid-portal-2.0.16
11/30/2014  11:34 AM         2,029,158 usergrid-portal-2.0.16.tar.gz
               2 File(s)     50,610,195 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  336,509,812,736 bytes free
```

However when I try to start usergrid after that, it throws a message on startup indicating it failed to start although Jetty seemed to have started:

```
C:\Users\sgs\.a127\usergrid>a127 usergrid start
starting...
timeout
failed to start. Log tail:
INFO: Registering Spring bean, rootResource, of type org.apache.usergrid.rest.Ro
otResource as a root resource class
Nov 30, 2014 11:35:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProv
iderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, systemResource, of type org.apache.usergrid.rest.
SystemResource as a root resource class
Nov 30, 2014 11:35:52 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProv
iderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, propertiesResource, of type org.apache.usergrid.r
est.test.PropertiesResource as a root resource class
Nov 30, 2014 11:35:52 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationIm
pl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.18 11/22/2013 01:21 AM'
Nov 30, 2014 11:35:53 AM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.


C:\Users\sgs\.a127\usergrid>a127 usergrid portal
Usergrid doesn't appear to be running. Run with --start option or execute 'a127
usergrid start' first.
```

Have you seen this before & any ideas on how to ensure usergrid start?

-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the jar file size, it should be 48581037. You might just need to delete the file and let a127 download it again.

Comment: Never mind Scott, I figured it out .. thanks much for the tip.